# Using v-for range on attributes in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a long list of images, but want to display only 5 of them

Here's the code I've tried

```
        <ul>
            <li v-for="index in 5" :key="index">
                <img v-bind:src="image.ImageUrl[index]" />
            </li>
        </ul>
```

If the use the follow it works, but then it displays all the images

```
        <ul>
            <li v-for="image in Images">
                <img v-bind:src="image.ImageUrl" />
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the index (and bringing logic to your template), you could do this programatically.

[Computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) are perfect for these kind of tasks:

(Replace `{{ image }}` with your `<img ..>`)

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    images: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
  },
  computed: {
    imagesSliced() {
      return this.images.slice(0,5);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(image, index) in imagesSliced" :key="index">
    {{ image }}
    <!--  <img v-bind:src="image.ImageUrl" /> -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to index `Images` to get the `image` first, try `Images[index].ImageUrl` instead of `image.ImageUrl[index]` where `image` is not defined inside the first for loop:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="index in 5" :key="index">
    <img v-bind:src="Images[index].ImageUrl" />
  </li>
</ul>
```